# Extract value from jsr223 sampler

Tags: groovy, jmeter, jmeter-5.0

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9708N.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kTn1z.png)

How to extract maxValue_max from jsr223 sampler to the next request?
I see that the sampler determines the maximum value, how now to extract and use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do have the value written into a [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) already, you can just call `${maxValue_max}` where required and the variable will be resolved to its respective value.

Or if you prefer Groovy scripting you can use [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) like:

[image]

You might also want to call [`SampleResult.setIgnore()` function](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html#setIgnore--) somewhere in your script so the JSR223 Sampler won't appear in the test results or just switch to [JSR223 Post-Processor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor).

Check out [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy) for more information on this SampleResult and other [JMeter API](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/index.html) shorthands available for the JSR223 Test Elements

Comment: Вы случаем на русском не говорите?)
Возможно я некорректно ее использую, уже несколько дней ломаю голову. 
Просто вызвать не получается, логика написана на груви. 
Функция груви должна быть такой ${__groovy(vars.get('max_Value_max'),)}
А где именно ее вызывать? В value реквеста? (я джметр неделю изучаю, поэтому некоторых простых вещей не понимаю)

Comment: `max_Value_max` и `maxValue_max` это две разные переменные, у вас определена и соответственно вам нужна вторая

Comment: Посмотрите, пожалуйста, вопрос, если не сложно: 
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1379282/Как-вытянуть-ключ-максимального-значения-из-массива

Все оказалось гораздо проще, чем я думал, переменную действительно было легко вызвать и я сделал это сразу. Вот только у максимального числа был еще и ключ, который тоже нужно передавать отдельным значением.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to extract, it's part of JMeter variables as you can see in Debug Sampler response

You can use it as `${maxValue_max}` expect inside JSR223 script where you should use `vars.get("maxValue_max")` syntax

See [how to reference a variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#how)

> Referencing a variable in a test element is done by bracketing the variable name with '${' and '}'.